# Замыкание в интервалах

Tags: javascript

```
var num = 0;
var max = 10;
var intervalId = null;

function incrementNumber() {
    num++;
    document.body.innerHTML += 5
    //if the max has been reached, cancel all pending executions
    if (num == max) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        alert('Done');
    }
}
intervalId = setInterval(incrementNumber, 500);
```

Вопрос, почему num  сохраняется и постоянно увеличивается num++? Мы ведь не возвращаем num.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все просто. Для функции `incrementNumber`, и вообще для всего пространства, где выполняются ваши действия, `num` глобальна. И, в любом случае, вы имеете дело с одной и той же переменной. Но вот ваше "Мы ведь не возвращаем num", мне совершенно непонятно.